# how to extract mulitple method names which are used inside of a function

Tags: javascript, regex

I get a Javascript function in the form of string from ui-ace as follows,

`aceCode = "function funtionName(){ methodAdd(4,8); methodSub(8,4)}";`

And I want to extract only method names as `methodAdd,methodSub` from `aceCode`, is their any option to do this?

Comment: `funtionName` is also method name, you dont' want it?

Comment: no i wrote regex for that as `var regex = /function\s*([^\(]*)\(/;`

Comment: Check [`([a-zA-Z]+)\(\d+,\d+\);?\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/vA8nO8/1)

Comment: The aceCode, doesn't have a valid Javascript in response .

Comment: @Tushar i am only getting `methodAdd`  as an first object of array i am not getting both `methodSub` in that

Comment: @sanjeev i did't get you? that is only an example code i gave

Comment: You might come up with sth. like `\b(\w+)\(`, see a demo here: https://regex101.com/r/kS5bS4/1 Returns `functionName`, `methodAdd` and `methodSub`.

Comment: I mean to say that , '"function funtionName(){ methodAdd(4,8); methodSub(8,4)}"'  this is not a valid JavaScript code

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: i am extracting method names becoz i already derived them in another .js file and i want to store the names so that i extract only that all functions from that .js file which the user used while writing the function

Answer (score 2):

It is very very fragile trying to parse JavaScript by yourself, just using regular expressions. Use a proper JavaScript parser, like [Esprima](http://esprima.org/), then scan the abstract syntax tree.

```js
function findFunctionCalls(ast) {
  if (Array.isArray(ast)) {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], ast.map(findFunctionCalls));
  } else if (ast.type == "CallExpression") {
    return [ast.callee.name];
  } else if (ast.type == "ExpressionStatement") {
    return findFunctionCalls(ast.expression);
  } else if (ast.body) {
    return findFunctionCalls(ast.body);
  } else {
    console.error("Oops, I didn't cover that case (" + ast.type + ")");
    return [];
  }
}

var aceCode = "function funtionName(){ methodAdd(4,8); methodSub(8,4)}";
var ast = esprima.parse(aceCode);
console.log(findFunctionCalls(ast));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jquery/esprima/2.7.1/esprima.js"></script>

<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

This is a minimal snippet to demonstrate the idea on the posted minimal example; it probably does not cover all the node types, but it is trivial to extend it for the missing ones.

Answer (score -2):

An approach with a regular expression would be:

```
\b(\w+)\(
```

This is, look for a word boundary (`\b`), capture every word character (`\w`) in a group, which is followed by a parenthesis. Look [here for a working demo](https://regex101.com/r/kS5bS4/1).

To only get `methodAdd`, `methodSub` and generally functions inside the curly brackets, you could change the regex to:

```
(\w*)\([^)]*\)(?!{)
```

See [another working demo](https://regex101.com/r/kS5bS4/4) for this solution here. Hint: Thanks to Harpreet Singh for pointing out that the first one was not working properly.

Comment: Your second regEx will not match "methodAdd()"

Comment: @HarpreetSingh: Did you check the link and have you read the matched groups on the right? OP does not need the parentheses.

Comment: Yes, OP does not need parenthesis but its actually not matching the function without parenthesis. check this https://regex101.com/r/kS5bS4/3

Comment: @HarpreetSingh Thanks for pointing this one out, I have changed the regex and added a negative lookahead.